# Compressing compass generated sprites with Rails and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, compass-sass, image-optimization

I'm having trouble right now trying to make sure that my images are optimized. I've manually optimized every image that I can, and I found [this handy gem](https://github.com/toy/image_optim) in combination with [this](https://github.com/mooktakim/image_optim_bin) to automate the process in future.

I have two remaining images that [pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) is warning me about, and those are compass generated sprite files. While the image_optim gem is great, it's not compressing the generated images.

I've already forked the heroku ruby buildpack to modify it for other reasons, so I'm open to solutions involving that. I did try this:

```
log("image_optim") do
  sprite_path = Dir["#{Rails.root.join('public', 'assets').to_s}/sprite-*.png"]
  image_optim = ImageOptim.new
  image_optim.optimize_images!(sprite_path)
end
```

But I ended up getting this error, which seemed unrelated to me, but it was definitely this code that triggered it:

```
/tmp/buildpack_f3d33d60-fd28-45d8-ac44-d1878918103e/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:124:in `block in run_assets_precompile_rake_task': uninitialized constant LanguagePack::Rails4::Rails (NameError)
```

Any help would be appreciated!